# How to trim a vector in r?

Tags: r, desctools

I am trying to trim a vector in r by percentage. The function should discard the lowest 5% and the highest 5% values of X, and then return the mean, variance, and median of X.

```
my_aggregation <- function(x,is.truncated=FALSE){
  if (is.truncated==FALSE) return(data.frame(mean = mean(x), med = median(x), var = var(x)))  
  if (is.truncated==TRUE) Trim(x,0.05) return(data.frame(mean = mean(x), med = median(x), var = var(x)))  
  
}
```

I have tried to assign to a new variable like this

```
  if (is.truncated==TRUE) x2 <- Trim(x,0.05) return(data.frame(mean = mean(x2), med = median(x2), var = var(x2)))
```

With no luck. The reason I dont find the problem is because I am new and also when I run this

```
   my_aggregation <- function(x,is.truncated=FALSE){  
  if (is.truncated==FALSE) return(data.frame(mean = mean(x), med = median(x), var = var(x)))  
  if (is.truncated==TRUE)return(data.frame(mean = mean(x), med = median(x), var = var(x)))  
  if (is.truncated=="BOTH") return({x*2})
}
```

Everything works perfectly fine. Maybe it has something to do with the Trim() function, but I dont know what is is exactly. Anyway, this is the error I am getting.

```
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"  if (is.truncated==FALSE) return(data.frame(mean = mean(x), med = median(x), var = var(x)))  
  if (is.truncated==TRUE) Trim(x,0.05) return"
>   if (is.truncated=="BOTH") return({x*2})
Error: object 'is.truncated' not found
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

If you have other suggestions of how I might achieve the same results, I am all ears.

Comment: You seem to have mixed up the syntax. Where is the function `Trim` defined, or are you trying to define that inside your function?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what `Trim` is in your question, nor the significance of `is.truncated`. My best guess is that you wish to get your summary statistics but control whether the user can trim off the bottom 5%, the top 5%, or both. If so, you could do:

```r
my_aggregation <- function(x, truncate = c("none", "lower", "upper", "both")) 
{
  truncate <- match.arg(truncate, truncate)
  keep <- !logical(length(x))
  if(truncate == "lower" | truncate == "both") 
    keep[x < quantile(x, 0.05)] <- FALSE
  if(truncate == "upper" | truncate == "both")
    keep[x > quantile(x, 0.95)] <- FALSE
  x <- x[keep]
  return(data.frame(min = min(x), max = max(x), mean = mean(x), 
                    med = median(x), var = var(x)))
}
```

That allows you to do:

```r
my_aggregation(1:100, "none")
#>   min max mean  med      var
#> 1   1 100 50.5 50.5 841.6667

my_aggregation(1:100, "lower")
#>   min max mean med var
#> 1   6 100   53  53 760

my_aggregation(1:100, "upper")
#>   min max mean med var
#> 1   1  95   48  48 760

my_aggregation(1:100, "both")
#>   min max mean  med   var
#> 1   6  95 50.5 50.5 682.5
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what you wanted to do is

```
my_aggregation <- function(x, is.truncated=FALSE){
  
  require(DescTools)      

  if (is.truncated)   # a '== TRUE' chunk would be obsolete
    x <- Trim(x, trim = 0.05)
  
  return(c(mean=mean(x), median=median(x), var=var(x)))
}         

set.seed(34)
x <- runif(100)

my_aggregation(x)
#       mean     median        var 
# 0.51284962 0.50315252 0.08925482 

my_aggregation(x, is.truncated = TRUE)
#       mean     median        var 
# 0.51390241 0.50315252 0.07350477
```

Note that you do not store the result of the trimming statement, if you code like

```
 if (is.truncated==TRUE) Trim(x,0.05) return(data.frame(mean = mean(x), med = median(x), var = var(x)))
```

Using indentation would reveal the logic of your code, which is

```
 if (is.truncated==TRUE) 
   Trim(x,0.05)

 return(data.frame(mean = mean(x), med = median(x), var = var(x)))
```

So you see that only `Trim(x,0.05)` is executed in condition of `is.truncated`. Use {} to combine multiple steps, e.g.

```
 if (is.truncated==TRUE) {
   x <- Trim(x,0.05)   # you have to redefine x here, if it should be used afterwards
   return(data.frame(mean = mean(x), med = median(x), var = var(x)))
 }
```

Last one: Why returning a data.frame if you only have three numeric values as result? In general use the simplest possible data structure for your problem, which here is a numeric vector.